# Classification of logit and probit models

Tags: logistic, probit, choice-modeling

[Savolainen et al. (2011)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0001457511000765) has a review of discrete choice models used in accident analysis. The paper offers a classification of these models (see image), but some models (e.g. 'Partial proportional odds model', 'Classification and regression tree' and 'Heteroskedastic ordered
logit/probit model') mentioned in the paper don't quite fit that taxonomy.

Are there any good references on the classification of these models with explanations on the variations? Something similar to [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/a-tour-of-machine-learning-algorithms/) classification of machine learning models is what I'm looking for.

[image: taxonomy]